# Importing multiple raster images in PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qgis-plugins, postgis-2.0

I have several raster images for one area and I am trying to import these multiple raster images in PostGIS. Is there a efficient way to import these raster images at once?

Comment: Yes, using raster2pgsql it is trivial to script something like that.